# Arduino String comparison returning false... using .readStringUntil function

Tags: c++, string, arduino, comparison, string-comparison

I have managed to save and retrieve a String of IDs from SD and the problem that I'm facing is with comparing the two Strings. Using .readStringUntil('\n') for retrieving IDs from SD line by line.

[Here is the complete Arduino sketch](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/10989588/)

@line211

[Here is the serial out to show the two variables...](http://ibin.co/20g1NMVMgMlY)

Thanks :)

Comment: Please narrow down the code to just the relevant parts, then edit your question to include that code. Links can't be trusted as they can go stale. The same with the output, copy and paste the *text* into the question, as well as the output you *expect* to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

Had to add codesFoundOnSD.trim(); to remove any extra or hidden text or a carriage return...